# How to show only specific UIactivity Items In uiactivitycontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I would like to show only mail, imessages and whatsapp in uiactivitycontroller.
Exclude activity types only excludes default types and shows others.

Is there a way to show only the above mentioned activity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you ever able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just Add a method named **shouldExcludeActivityType** to **UIActivityViewController** and **return** **false** for the activity items you want show and **return true** for the rest of the items.

```
import UIKit

class MyActivityViewController: UIActivityViewController {

    func _shouldExcludeActivityType(activity: UIActivity) -> Bool {
        let activityTypesToExclude = [
        "com.apple.mail",
        "com.apple.iMesaage",
         "Whatsapp bundle id"
        ]

        if let actType = activity.activityType() {
            if activityTypesToExclude.contains(actType)       {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more. Myactivityviewcontroller is not getting called at all